# Laravel 5.5 mailgun not sending emails - no errors

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

I am trying to send emails with mailgun but they won't send and I have no idea why because i don't get any errors at all.

This is my code:

mail.php:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
```

services.php:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('sandbox1e...60.mailgun.org'),
    'secret' => env('key-146...419'),
],
```

EmailController.php:

```
public function send($email, $uuid = null)
{
    if($uuid == null){
        $uuid = User::get()->where('customer_email' , $email)->first()->email_confirmed;
    }

    return Mail::to($email)->send(new ConfirmEmail($uuid));

}
```

ConfirmEmail.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ConfirmEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $uuid;

    public function __construct($uuid)
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('mailgun@sandbox1e17506823f2490ba9cc78cbbc2adb60.mailgun.org')
            ->view('emails.confirm');
    }
}
```

I have added the emailadress I want to send to in mailgun, but it's not working. Am I doing something wrong or is there any way I can debug this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('sandbox1e...60.mailgun.org'),
    'secret' => env('key-146...419'),
],
```

The env function looks for an environment variable with the name you provide and returns the value. You should change it to the name of an environment variable and define it in your .env or don't use the env function, but that's not recommended.

Comment: Sometimes APIs provide different types of keys, so the way you shown the example 'sandbox1e.....' and 'key....' really helped me a lot identifying the correct key / value. <3 Thanks man.

Answer (score 9):

Whereas [Esteban Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947640/esteban-garcia)'s answer is correct, I to wish improve it with code snippets showing how exactly the configuration should look like:

In your `config/services.php`, leave the configuration as shown below:

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],
```

In your `.env` file, that is where you define the actual mailgun credentials:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox1e...60.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-146...419
```

Comment: not sure if this is because of an update but in laravel7 it should be: `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun`

Answer (score -3):

> In your laravel .env configure these things

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandboxXXXXXX.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxXXXXX.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=XXXXXXX
```

> After that goto vendor->guzzlehttp->src->client.php find 
>   configureDefaults() method have array name called defaults that array
>   have verify => true change to false

```
'verify' => false,
```

> then configure mail.php

```
  'from' => ['address' => 'youremail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'yourname'],
```

> go to route.php and test email is working or not send simple email.
>   plz make sure you install laravel mail class or install using this
>   command **composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

Route::get('/', function () {

    $data = [
        'title'=>'title here',
        'Content'=>'simple content'
    ];

    Mail::send('email.test',$data, function ($message){

        $message->to('youremail@gmail.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
    });

});
```

Comment: Editing things in the `vendor` folder is a bad idea.